# MongoDB 2.4 upgrade considerations

Tags: java, mongodb

We have currently MongoDB 2.4 installed, application which uses the database is written in Java. Currently we don't have any major problems with Mongo, but I'm little worried that we bump something in the future because we are running pretty old version of Mongo. We cannot just upgrade Mongo itself to the latest version, we would also need to upgrade the Java driver and that would need quite a lot of refactoring to the code. Our OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and we are upgrading that to 16.04 in the next few months. So my question is, is it safe to continue using 2.4 or is there maybe some limitations why we should upgrade to a newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your code is still using `DBObject` or `BasicDBObject`. If that's the case then updating to newer version will pretty much mean that you're going to have to refactor your codes to use `Document` instead. It can still work, just not recommended IIRC. I can confidently say that it will be a lot of work.They are not syntactically complex, but it's definitely not something you can solve with find and replace.

If your application does not run a lot of aggregation or complex queries (especially those involving arrays), you might be safe where you are. Upgrading gives you access to new neat operators. I remember there are a few for aggregations like `$lookup` and arrays and upcoming `$graphLookup`. If you don't need those then maybe you're fine.

For certain use cases, upgrading might save you the need of massaging the results in application layer, which I think is a major point for long term convenience.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks! I'll think we stay where we are for now.